# Solving the canonical form of an elliptic PDE [HEAT EQUATION]

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have the following PDE

$$
\lambda_h \frac{\partial^2 \theta}{\partial x^2} + \lambda_c V \frac{\partial^2 \theta}{\partial y^2} + \theta (k_1) + k_2 = 0
$$

This turns out to be an Elliptic second order linear PDE. On converting to the canonical form it takes the following shape

$$\frac{\partial^2 \theta}{\partial \alpha^2}+\frac{\partial^2 \theta}{\partial \beta^2}=q_1\theta+q_2
$$
where
$q_1=-k_1/(\lambda_cV),q_2=-k_2/(\lambda_cV),  \beta=-px, \alpha=y$ and $p^2=\frac{\lambda_cV}{\lambda_h}$

What should be the approach now to move forward with this canonical form ?
Should I introduce a Laplace transform or is there a standard method for such a PDE ?

[The Laplace equation would have a zero on the RHS with no $\theta$ term and the Poisson equation a function of $x$ and $y$ on RHS with no $\theta$ term. So this canonical form doesn't correspond to any of them ?]

The PDE needs to be solved on a rectangular region where $x$ varies between $0$ to $1$ and $y$ varies between $0$ to $1$. The boundary conditions are of Neumann type.

$$\frac{\partial \theta(0,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial \theta(1,y)}{\partial x}=0 $$

$$\frac{\partial \theta(x,0)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial \theta(x,1)}{\partial y}=0 $$

**Attempt**

As suggested i tried as following using seperation of variables:
$$\theta_{\alpha\alpha}+\theta_{\beta\beta}-q_1\theta=0$$

let   $$\theta=X(\alpha)Y(\beta)$$

This gives: $$X^{''}Y+XY^{''}-q_1XY=0$$
$$\frac{X^{''}}{X}+\frac{Y^{''}}{Y}-q_1=0$$

This is not turning towards a usual variable separation problem due to the variable $q_1$. Any further suggestions ?

Comment: What is the domain you're trying to solve your PDE on? Do you have boundary conditions?

Comment: @Dmoreno I have edited the question to add the boundary conditions.

Comment: Have you tried using separation of variables?

Comment: @Dmoreno No , i encountered this problem while analysing a heat exchanger system. I did go through some material for equations of similar type from standard PDE textbooks but encountered homogenous type and with no $u$ term. They all do use seperation of variables. Should i try the standard u= XY seperation route ?

Comment: Yes, but first notice that your PDE is non-homogenous because of the $q_2$ term. I would first solve for the eigenmodes satisfying the same equation and BCs but for $q_2 = 0$ and then expand.

Comment: @Dmoreno Thanks for the prompt response. I will try it tommorow first thing with $q_2=0$ . But i am in dark with your second suggestion about expanding when i do include $q_2$. It would be helpful if you could point me to a reference employing this expansion strategy

Comment: You're welcome. Here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303424/pde-heat-equation-problem/1303444#1303444) you can find a short discussion about how to proceed with this kind of problems. I'm sure I have helped someone else with a similar question but I cannot find it among my answers at the moment. Sorry!

Comment: @Dmoreno ok..great. will revert back once i try this out. If you get the time do look for the similar answer you were mentioning.

Comment: @Dmoreno I tried separation of variables putting $q_2=0$. But got stuck as can be seen in the attempt.  Any help would be really useful.